# I don't want to create a reg. key, I want to open a reg. key--but there's no provision to here:

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

VB code here, `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145679`, uses

**RegOpenKeyEx, QueryValueEx, SetValueEx**

to effect change on a registry key, and it works for me.

I looked for something similar written in C#, but didn't find anything other than a code sample that was also purported to work by some other site's independent confirmation.  The code I found is here:  `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197002(v=vs.85).aspx`

But I can't make it work.  Maybe it's because what I'm trying the code on already has a key (the code wants to create one with **IERegCreateKeyEx**).

Is it not working because the key I want to change has to be opened first?  If so, what is the open function in the following list of functions?  `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh802026(v=vs.85).aspx`

And if so how would it be used with the found code above? Thank you for any help.

Comment: According to the documentation of `IERegCreateKeyEx`, if the key already exists, it'll simply open it for you. Is that what you want? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197002%28v=vs.85%29

Comment: Yes, I want that functionality, but was unaware IERegCreateKeyEx handled opening in that way.  I'll try it.  Thank you.

Comment: I give up on this.   I've tried everything, I don't know how to call the functions in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145679 (about a third of the way down the page ) so that an IE value changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just looking for [`RegistryKey.OpenSubKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wf60cbhz). It's not clear where Internet Explorer comes in, frankly...

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I got on this whole Internet Explorer jag because the only C# example I could find was one for IE (which in a happy coincidence I'm also applying it to).  But instead of just supplying generic registry functions, the codebase imports ieframe.dll and uses functions with IE appended to the front.  I don't know why it uses those and not more generically suited functions.  I don't know if they're more efficiently written for IE or what.